# Azure Bot Framework - resizable FormFlow window

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to build a simple dialog with the FormFlow but the options I want to display are quite long and are cut off. Any idea how I can make the dialog window resizable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), where you might be able to tweak the CSS by building a custom version of it, you can't resize the dialog window.

The best option here would be removing the "I Would Like" part of your button text.